# Can the Location and Privacy settings be reset programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the iOS Settings app, choosing General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy resets the device's location and privacy settings.  Can this be done programmatically in Objective-C?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: This is for testing, so my test app can repeatedly test the case where the user is prompted to allow calendar access, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be done through code (at least not through App Store approved public APIs anyway). Only the user can do this through the Settings app.

Answer (score -1):

You could continually remove the app from the device and then run it again to keep checking.

Comment: Deleting and reinstalling does not reset the user's chosen privacy setting for the app.

Comment: Your right.  Kinda annoying tho that they would keep data for an app that i have deleted.